# Sort by Pattern

Tags: java, android, sorting, kotlin

I cannot achieve sorting by a specific pattern (order) in Kotlin. Lets say I have a list of Strings [Yellow, Red, Green, Blue]. I want to sort them by a specific pattern [Red, Green, Blue, Yellow]. (Keep in mind that the list sometimes differs) [Green, Blue, Yellow] or [Yellow, Red, Blue]. Is there is a way to achieve it in a nice way?

Kind regards.

Comment: What's the sort criteria? From the example you mentioned it is impossible to determine that sort criteria. Is it alphabetical sort?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, order of colors has to be as in given pattern.
Then you can just remove elements from pattern that are not in input list.

```
val pattern = listOf("Red", "Green", "Blue", "Yellow")

val input1 = listOf("Green", "Blue", "Yellow").toSet()
val input2 = listOf("Yellow", "Red", "Blue").toSet()

val sorted1 = pattern.filter { input1.contains(it) }
val sorted2 = pattern.filter { input2.contains(it) }

println(sorted1) // [Green, Blue, Yellow]
println(sorted2) // [Red, Blue, Yellow]
```

This will not work if your input can contain duplicate colors though.